# Where to check the Mapped Property of lookup ID column

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am having this lookup column(`ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookupId`) in lists. I want the Mapped property for this column where to check?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Site Settings
- Site Collection Administraction

  - Search Schema
  - Go to The Crawled Property link and enter the name and see what the mapped property to that crawled one

Comment: When i use this in rest search method that lookup column shows null values

Comment: so what you are saying that you that the filed ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookupId on the list has a value, but when you query it, it returns null? Did you check all the list items? Do they all return null? Did you map the ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookupId to any of the RefinableIntegerxx ?

Comment: ya i checked for some other list items it is coming , No i am not mapped to any refinable integer.

Comment: I would suggest you map it to one of the RefinableInteger00 (for example if it is not mapped to other) and you should use that in your query instead of ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookupId and see what happens